# Redux update state array object property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I have the following function that takes an action type and returns a new state, however since I didnt like the "slice" method I thought I would use the concat method instead. The commented out code was the original "slice" solution to update the state with the newly updated object. However, it doesn't work and and I am not even getting an error.

My approach is to join the existing state with the n

```
function posts(state = [], action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'INCREMENT_LIKES':
            const i = action.index;

            //console.log(newState);    
            // let newState =  [ 
            //  // ...state.slice(0, i),
            //  // {...state[i], likes: state[i].likes + 1},
            //  // ...state.slice(i + 1),
            // ]
            // console.log(newState);
            return state.concat([{...state[i], likes: state.likes +1}]);
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default posts;
```

Comment: try to debug your store via redux developer tools and you will see that these two snippets doesn't produce same results

Comment: Atleast `likes: state[i].likes +1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line will always append new element at the end of the state `return state.concat([{...state[i], likes: state[i].likes +1}]);`

According to commented code you need to update `i`th element. You could do it using map.

```
return state.map((item, i) => (
  i === action.index ? {...item, likes: item.likes + 1} : item)
);
```